# Excel IF/AND formula using an table from Access

Tags: excel, ms-access, worksheet-function

I export an Access table to Excel and am trying to make a formula that if certain criteria in 3 of the columns on the table are met it will subtotal a forth column. I keep getting the answer of "0", when I know the answer should be 6615. Any suggestions of how to change the formula are welcomed.

using .xlsx as extension formula looks like:

```
=IF(AND(Table_ATOD_PS_FY_1314[LINE '#]="82B",Table_ATOD_PS_FY_1314[FACILITY NUMBER]="707233",Table_ATOD_PS_FY_1314[FUNDING DESC]="WWC"), SUBTOTAL(9,Table_ATOD_PS_FY_1314[TOTAL INV]),0)
```

using .xls as extension formula looks like:

```
=IF(AND(Sheet1!$J$2:$J$628="82B",Sheet1!$G$2:$G$628="707233",Sheet1!$Q$2:$Q$628="WWC"), SUBTOTAL(9,Sheet1!$R$2:$R$628),0)
```

Answer (score 1):

`AND` cannot take arrays and return arrays. Use `SUMIFS` instead:

```
=SUMIFS(Table_ATOD_PS_FY_1314[TOTAL INV], Table_ATOD_PS_FY_1314[LINE '#],"82B",Table_ATOD_PS_FY_1314[FACILITY NUMBER],"707233",Table_ATOD_PS_FY_1314[FUNDING DESC],"WWC")
```

Or the range version:

```
=SUMIFS(Sheet1!$R$2:$R$628, Sheet1!$J$2:$J$628, "82B", Sheet1!$G$2:$G$628, "707233", Sheet1!$Q$2:$Q$628, "WWC")
```

Though I'm not sure why you didn't do the sum in access since it's easier I think to do it there with the query design.

`SUMIFS` has syntax:

```
=SUMIFS( SumRange, Range1, Condition1, Range2, Condition2, ... )
```